# Button HTML not showing

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, knockout.js, visual-studio-2017

I am creating a web application that communicates with a wcf service, to get data from a database. I'm using knockout js and Visual Studio 2017.

The problem I'm having is that when I'm pressing CTRL+F5 (start without debugging), my HTML button is not showing up, while it is when pressing F5 (start with debugging). Also, when pressing the button while in debug mode, it does not seem to reach the javascript file. (btw I'm new to programming)

HTML code:

```
<h1>Welcome to this simple web service.</h1>
<p> Get personal information by inserting your personal number. </p>

<b>Personal Number: </b><span>
    <input data-bind="textInput: PersonalNumber" />
</span>
<button data-bind="click: $root.FindPerson">Find</button>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.PersonalNumber = ko.observable();
    this.FindPerson = function (personalnumber) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Service1.svc/GetData',
            data: ko.toJSON({ personalnumber: this.PersonalNumber }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: I have used the following references, that don't show up in the post for some reason:

    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/KOViewModelThings.js"></script>

Comment: This looks like an issue with visual studio rather than your code. But, can you check the browser's console for any errors when *the button doesn't show up*